# Full Adder Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, resistors, circuit-design, adder

This circuit is based around the SN74HC283 4 bit full adder.

- What purpose does the resistor network serve?
- Will this circuit work without any resistors, i.e. using raw inputs and outputs?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Having floating inputs **MAY** be OK for TTL inputs, but all these ICs are CMOS and must not float. Fresh out of college, I assisted a senior engineer debug about a 1,000-SSI data multiplexor for 10 or 15 sensors. I learned how CMOS worked ----- often erroneously ---- with no grounds or power to the ICs. Instead, the ESD diodes sufficed. Instead of 0/+12volts, the ICs often had +0.6 and +11.4 volts. Tooke a while to discover these; solution was to have the wire-wrap person use a magnifying glass on EACH of 1,000 ICs and ensure pins 7/14 or pins 8/16 were properly tied. A useful lesson for me.

Answer (score 1):

When the switches are closed, it is easy to see a direct connection from 5V to the input pins, which is read as a digital 1. If the switches were open, and those resistors weren't there, those nodes are left floating. This floating voltage could be read as a 1, it could be read as a 0. The adder would behave erratically. It would definitely read high signals correctly, but it wouldn't reliably read low signals. The resistors keep the voltage on the input pins from floating by pulling the signal to ground when the switches aren't closed.

If those switches were replaced with "Single Pole Double Throw" switches, it could work without those resistors. An example of how the single pole double throw switch would need hooked up is shown in the schematic below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3cdkN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: right, that makes sense.  Thanks for the swift reply.  Sorry to be a pain, but the current limiting resistors (100ohm) are purely for the led's sake, right?  The circuit will function without those?

Comment: @Steve: If you don't use the 100 Ohm resistors in series with the LEDs, you may destroy the LEDs.  These resistors control the current drawn by the LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

The 10K pulldown resistors ensure that the inputs to the 'HC283 will be Low when the switches are open.

An unconnected CMOS input may float randomly between Low and High, as the input is very high impedance.